# Bad request on RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule admin/(.*)? ../back/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

My `admin` files located on `../back` so I wrote `RewriteRule admin/(.*)? ../back/$1` but when I trying to access `http://mysite.local/admin/` I will get this message:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

My files/folders structures are :

```
Root
|--back
|--lib
|--public
|--|--index.php
|--|--.htaccess
```

Comment: Doesn't work like that. The rewrite only serves to make a different request. It can't allow access to a part of the website that's not exposed. You might be able to create an `Alias` to provide access to that directory instead.

Comment: Thanks, how can I use `Alias` for this ?

Comment: [Read this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: @arco444 I use `Alias` but I get 500 Internal Server Error, my `Alias` is : `Alias /admin/ ../back`

Comment: That will also not work. Read the documentation carefully.